# A small amendment to chat FAQ

Tags: feature-request, chat, faq-update-request

For my original question I've found the answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80082/allow-owner-of-message-to-delete-them-in-chat).  However, in the FAQ, I think it would be useful to indicate explicitly that one cannot delete messages older than 120s.  So, I propose the modification of this part: https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#talk with the following:

> You have 120 seconds to edit **or delete** your messages.

Answer (score 8):

I propose:

> You have 120 seconds to edit your messages. After this 2 minute window, messages can neither be edited nor deleted - except by moderators.

Comment: +1 for being more informative.

Comment: Seems too redundant. The entire first sentence is covered by the second sentence. I'd say just use the second sentence.

Comment: Redundancy is _sometimes_ worth it. I'd add the OP's "__or delete__" to the first sentence here too.

Comment: I agree with @Mark - this is a FAQ, not a [your favourite programming language] function :)