# Timing for Delete Chat in chat rooms

Tags: discussion, chat

I noticed we can also `edit/delete` our post in chat room. popup like below image.

> [image]

But I also noticed we can't `edit/delete` post after some time, popup will looking like as below image, so **I just want to know how much in time period we can edit/delete post in chat room? And why it is not possible for life time?**

> [image]

Comment: @Yannis according to faq and [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80083/152859) it's 2 minutes.. has it been changed?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd 2m it is then! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, according to the [chat faq](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#talk):

> If you make a mistake when entering a message, press the <kbd>↑</kbd> up arrow to
>   edit your last message … or press  <kbd>esc</kbd> to cancel editing. **You have 120
>   seconds to edit your messages**. All edited messages have a small edit
>   indicator.

Same holds for delete, and some interesting explanation is given in this [other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80083/152859).

Regarding "why it is not possible for life time", balpha who is the developer writing the code behind the chat, said in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80085/152859):

> We're talking about chat here. Conversation. Talking. You can't go
>   back to last weeks party, choose the things you never should have
>   said, and un-say them. In particular, that could quite well remove any
>   sense from the rest of the conversation that was not deleted.

And I tend to agree.

Comment: Correct; the same holds for deleting.

Comment: Thanks @balpha, think the faq should be updated then to "You have 120 seconds to edit or delete your messages."?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Are you sure ..?

Comment: @CapDroid yes, developer just confirmed it so can't be more sure than that.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd 120 seconds means 2min, check image in my quesion, I can also see edit/delete tag. when i post 2 min ago

Comment: @CapDroid well, it might not be accurate to the second. Do you still see the links after 3 minutes? If you click edit or delete after two minutes, can you really edit or delete?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd seen my edited question & why it is not possible for life time?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd hmm. no i can't edit after 3 minutes. & why it is not possible for life time?

Comment: @CapDroid for the "why" part see my edit. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd hmm thanks...