# Why is there a timeout to delete your own chat messages?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

What is the reasoning behind not allowing one to delete his own chat message after 2 minutes? The timeout to edit messages is good enough, I think.

I don't see many cases where losing some old messages would be problematic (restricting the number old messages that can be deleted in a certain timeframe should be more than enough). (Credit goes to [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster)).

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80082/allow-owner-of-message-to-delete-them-in-chat/80085#80085

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ever try to refer back to an old comment conversation only to find that someone had deleted all their replies leaving you talking to yourself?

Now imagine that in chat, where conversations might go on for hours or *days*...

And yes, there are plenty of people who would do this, either out of fear or just to be jerks. Rate-limiting might eliminate the former, but weeding out everyone but jerks isn't exactly a compelling argument.

Comment: I agree with the spirit of this. So how should we approach situations where deletion of messages in chat is justified and flagging is not the best option (say you post something sensitive by mistake and don't wanna flag it to bring attention to mods and other 10kers)?

Comment: If you bring it to the attention of moderators (10K users can't see mod flags), they can not only delete it but also edit it and then *purge the history* so that the sensitive information isn't visible to anyone going forward. Request this specifically in your flag. You can also contact us (link at the bottom of the page...) however flagging is usually much more expedient.

Comment: thanks, is this also true for entire private 1-1 rooms?

Comment: If you want a room deleted, just ask for the room to be deleted. Much, much easier. Expecting a moderator (or anyone) to delete a non-trivial quantity of messages is unrealistic.

Comment: @AwalGarg There are no private rooms for regular users, private rooms are only allowed to exist if they are used for moderation and they can only be created by diamond moderators. Non-private rooms are indexed by Google, if you posted anything private there you probably lost control of it already.